# Improving select statement performance

Tags: mysql

I have a table with around 500,000 rows, with a composite primary key index. I'm trying a simple select statement as follows

```
select * from transactions where account_id='1' and transaction_id='003a4955acdbcf72b5909f122f84d';
```

The explain statement gives me this

```
id | select_type | table        | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | SIMPLE       | transactions | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 94      | const,const | 1    | 100.00    | NULL
```

My primary index is on account_id and transaction_id.
My engine is InnoDB.

When I run my query it takes around 156 milliseconds.

Given that explain shows that only one row needs to be examined, I'm not sure how to optimize this further. What changes can I do to significantly improve this?

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)

Comment: @Cynical that his query is taking too long and he's asking why and eventually how to optimize it?

Comment: "Too long" based on what? Since he's using a selection on the primary key, it's already the best search he can do, given this structure.

Comment: @Cynical the real problem was the total time it takes to update a particular transaction. the update statement was taking the same time as the select statement and so I assumed that if the search was faster, I could bulk update faster. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I'd just wait the 156 milliseconds

Comment: I'd guess that the index (primary) doesn't fit into memory, so you need to touch the drive. If you use InnoDB - check the buffer pool size. A query like this should't take more than 1ms on modern hardware.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I ran select count(*) from information_schema.innodb_buffer_page; and got 393216. Then I ran select
table_name as Table_Name, index_name as Index_Name,
count(*) as Page_Count, sum(data_size)/1024/1024 as Size_in_MB
from information_schema.innodb_buffer_page
group by table_name, index_name
order by Size_in_MB desc; and saw my index is 64 MB. If this is right, then it does look like my index is larger than buffer pool size

Comment: To find out buffer pool size you should execute `select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size`

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to speculate a bit, given the information provided: your primary key is composed of an integer field `account_id` and a `varchar` one called `transaction_id`.

Since they're both components of the `PRIMARY` index created when you defined them as `PRIMARY KEY(account_id, transaction_id)`, *as they are* they're the best you can have.

I think the bottleneck here is the `transaction_id`: as a string, it requires more effort to be indexed, and to be searched for. Changing its type to a different, easier to search one (i.e. numbers) would probably help.

The only other improvement I see is to simplify the `PRIMARY KEY` itself, either by removing the `account_id` field (it seems useless to me, since the `transaction_id` tastes like being unique, but that depends on your design) or by substitute the whole key with an integer, `AUTO INCREMENT` value (not recommended).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the transaction id data type. It's also not unique.

Comment: That sounds painfully wrong, but then you have no other choice than keeping the double key. On your other comment, you should check which part of the update takes time: if it is the selection of the row to update, then you're asking the right question, otherwise you have to investigate more.